# How to stop the existing task instance if the task is already running using BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file, task, scheduled-tasks

I created a scheduler task using bat query

```
SchTasks /Create /TN Test_backup /SC DAILY /MO 1 /ST 01:00 /RL HIGHEST /TR %BACKUP_BAT_PATH%sco_database_backup.bat /RU "SYSTEM" /F
```

Everything is creating well, but the only problem is that I can't find a parametr for setting "Stop the existing instance" value to "If the task is already running,the following rule applies" parametr. [image: This is what I am talking about]

How can I set this parametr using batch query?

Comment: I'd recommend you to create task manually, export it as XML, modify this XML (if needed) and create the task by importing this XML back. In this case you can specify all aspects of the task.

Comment: @montonero sounds good, thank you

Answer (score 0):

On the windows versions since vista the task scheduler writes the info about the started process in the event log.

You can get the info about your task with:

```
wevtutil qe Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational /q:*[System/EventID=129]/EventData[@Name='CreatedTaskProcess']/Data[@Name='TaskName']='\TASK_NAME'
```

Just change the `TASK_NAME` with the name of your task. Then you'll see information for the task including the PID. Once you have the PID you can kill it with `taskkill`. Though check the event log to see if you need to change your wevutil query.